# how to filter (or fetch) a listGrid when autofetchData: false

Tags: javascript, smartclient

I have a ListriGrid, I wanted to put `autoFetchData : false`
because I have a lot of data and I don't want to load it from the launch of the application, but it has caused me problems in the filter list !! example :  `ListGrid.fetchData ({id: 1})`
it doesn't work!
do you have any idea how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have dataSource attached to the grid?
If you do and it doesn't still load, try .fetchData() and then .filterData({id:1})
Also try first in the browser console .fetchData ({id: 1}) over the dataSource object and see what you get.

If to you have removed dataSource from the grid, try first loading array with .setData() or defining localDataSource with array.

Comment: I thank you even if the question was asked one year ago ;)

Comment: Welcome, that's the purpose of stack overflow :)
We are moving a bit away from smarclient, and going to bootstrap and angularjs. But I just don't want my smartclient knowledge to fade away :) want to share it :)
If you enjoy the answer and it does the job, you can select it as a correct answer and give me cheer up ;)